# Using Binding within multiple DialogWindows - canceling issue

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm building an application that supports customers and their purchases.
Each customer holds a list of purchases:

```
public class Customer
   {
       public string FirstName { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
       public string Address { get; set; }
       public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    ... //Some more properties...

       public List<Purchase> PurchasesList { get; set; }
   }

   public class Purchase
    {
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
       public int ProductSerialNumber { get; set; }
      public DateTime DateOfPurchase { get; set; }

    ...//Some more properties
  }
```

And I hold a list of customers:

```
public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
```

At some point I want to edit the customers' list and their purchases. To do that I bind the Customers' list to a ListView control in a DialogWindow (#1).
When the user double-clicks one of the customers, a new DialogWindow (#2) is opened that allows editing the customer's personal details and
his purchases - most of them are textboxes that allow editing and I bind them to the customer object within the customers' list.
When the user presses 'OK' button - the binding is performed (I chose UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit on all textboxes).

Dialog (#2) is now closed and the changes took place (I can see the changes on the ListView on Dialog (#1)).
The problem is if the user presses the 'Cancel' button on Dialog (#1) he expects that the changes will not take place (but actually the source had
already been updated).

How can I undo the changes? I don't want to hold a copy of Customers' list (this might be a very space consuming list)

Answer (score 0):

There is an interface called [IEditableObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.aspx), it is quite complex to use but it might be helpful, since it exists for that exact purpose: Cancelling edits.

You might not get around saving a copy of your list though unless you take note of exactly which items were edited and just store their original state.